# Pass a dynamic variable through URL php

Tags: php, mysql, url, variables

I'm not sure about the title, I tried my best.
I have a table displayed with information from a database using this file

display.php

```
<?php

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("tournaments") or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tournies") 
    or die(mysql_error());  

    echo '<table id="bets" class="tablesorter" cellspacing="0" summary="Datapass">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Tournament <br> Name</th> 
        <th>Pot</th> 
        <th>Maximum <br> Players</th> 
        <th>Minimum <br> Players</th> 
        <th>Host</th> 
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>';



    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

       $i=0; if( $i % 2 == 0 ) {
            $class = "";
        } else {
            $class = "";
        }

        echo "<tr" . $class . "><td>"; 
        echo $row['tour_name'];
        $tour_id = $row['tour_name'];
        echo "</td><td>"; 
        echo $row['pot']," Tokens";
        echo "</td><td class=\"BR\">"; 
        echo $row['max_players']," Players";
        echo "</td><td class=\"BR\">"; 
        echo $row['min_players']," Players";
        echo "</td><td class=\"BR\">";
        echo $row['host'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo "<input id=\"delete_button\" type=\"button\" value=\"Delete Row\" onClick=\"SomeDeleteRowFunction(this)\">";
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo "<form action=\"join.php?name=$name\" method=\"POST\" >";
        echo "<input id=\"join_button\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Join\">";
        echo "</td></tr>"; 
    } 

    echo "</tbody></table>";
?>
```

Basically I want the user to press a button from a row of the table and they go to a new page called join.php. I need the persons username and the name of the tournament from the row the clicked.

For example here's my page: [image: my page]

When they click the join button at the end of row one it should send them to

'join.php?name=thierusernamehere&tourname=dfgdds'

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: where's the username data?

Comment: Just add a hidden field (`echo "<input name=\"name\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"".$name."\">";` for example) to the form with the username & tourname.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<td><a href="join.php?name='.$row['name'].'&tourname='.$row['tour_name'].'">Join</a></td>'
```

Comment: `name` doesn't appear to be part of the resultset.

Comment: @AndreeCrist
Just had to fix a few naming errors and it worked like a charm, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to approach.

The easiest way is just `echo '<a href="join.php?name=' . $row['col_name'] . '">JOIN</a>';`

or you can use a form with hidden input and submit button.

BUT

Your code is really a mess, try to make your code more maintainable and readable. And do NOT use any `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated.

Read more about PDO:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/